# How to send DataGridView's data as email message?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm retrieve the data from SQL server and store it in a DataGridView. After this I need to send mail to my client. Whatever data is in DataGridView, I need to sent the DataGridView data to client as message.

I tried my best, but I can't add DataGridView data in message. Below is my code:

**loading datagridview from sql server**

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
Connection();
datatable.Load(new SqlCommand("select * from StudentMarksHistory", cs).ExecuteReader());
dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable.DefaultView;
cs.Close();
```

**sending mail to client**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    mailBody +="<tr>";
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        mailBody +="<td stlye='color:blue;'>" +cell.Value + "</td>";
    }
    mailBody +="</tr>";
}
mailBody +="</table>";

//your rest of the original code
mail.Body = mailBody;
```

It doesn't work in C# WinForms. What do I need to do? Give any idea please...

Comment: What doesn't work? Where is the email part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining mailBody AFTER you have already been using it.

This won't even compile.

I'm guessing you need to move the

```
string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";
```

Line to the top, certainly above the foreach.

Also, you need to actually Send the email, I don't see your code for that anywhere?

Comment: Well...it is now you have edited your question! Please post the complete code for this section if you expect us to be able to help you properly.